# problems with paypal module

Tags: perl, paypal-sandbox

is anyone ever tried this module NET::PayPal

because i tried it and i was getting this error

Authorization failed : 401 Unauthorized, {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"}

and am using valid client id and secret id

```
    use Net::PayPal;

$client_id = 'asdasdasdasdsadasdasd';
$client_secret = 'sadasdasdsadasdsad';
my $p = Net::PayPal->new($client_id, $client_secret);

my $payment = $p->get_payment( 'PAY-9D023728F47376036KE5OTKY' );
```

Comment: Are your credentials valid for the sandbox? According tot he [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::PayPal#GOING-LIVE), it goes to the sandbox by default and you need to switch it to `live` mode.

Comment: Crossposted to [PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1225086).

Comment: Did this solve your problem? I will write up an answer in that case.

Comment: yes I got authenticated now tho am still facing some problems my stack overflow  question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53117562/problems-with-internal-server-error-on-paypal-api)

Answer (score 1):

According [to the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::PayPal#GOING-LIVE), Net::PayPal always starts out in sandbox mode. You have to switch it to live mode in order to use your production credentials.

> ```
> Net::PayPal->live( 1 );
> my $pp = Net::PayPal->new($client_id, $secret);
> ```